# Numpy Installation on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, numpy, raspberry-pi, importerror

I am attempting to graph data from a particulate sensor using Python. However, I keep getting an import error of the following.

```
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: libopenblas.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I followed the link to the following troubleshooting guide but still am having troubles.

[numpy.org](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html)

please any guidance here is greatly appreciated.

full code below

```
import time
import board
import busio
from digitalio import DigitalInOut, Direction, Pull
from adafruit_pm25.i2c import PM25_I2C
from datetime import datetime
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

datetime1 = str(datetime.now())

reset_pin = None

i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA, frequency=100000)
pm25 = PM25_I2C(i2c, reset_pin)

extension = ".csv"
file_name = datetime1 + extension

def start_collection():
    global collecting
    collecting = True
    start_button.config(state="disabled")
    stop_button.config(state="normal")
    collect_data()

def stop_collection():
    global collecting
    collecting = False
    start_button.config(state="normal")
    stop_button.config(state="disabled")

def collect_data():
    if collecting:
        try:
            aqdata = pm25.read()
            concentration_units = (
                "Concentration Units (standard)\n"
                "---------------------------------------\n"
                "PM 1.0: {}\tPM2.5: {}\tPM10: {}\n"
                "Concentration Units (environmental)\n"
                "---------------------------------------\n"
                "PM 1.0: {}\tPM2.5: {}\tPM10: {}\n"
                "---------------------------------------\n"
                "Particles > 0.3um / 0.1L air: {}\n"
                "Particles > 0.5um / 0.1L air: {}\n"
                "Particles > 1.0um / 0.1L air: {}\n"
                "Particles > 2.5um / 0.1L air: {}\n"
                "Particles > 5.0um / 0.1L air: {}\n"
                "Particles > 10 um / 0.1L air: {}\n"
                "---------------------------------------"
            ).format(
                aqdata["pm10 standard"], aqdata["pm25 standard"], aqdata["pm100 standard"],
                aqdata["pm10 env"], aqdata["pm25 env"], aqdata["pm100 env"],
                aqdata["particles 03um"], aqdata["particles 05um"], aqdata["particles 10um"],
                aqdata["particles 25um"], aqdata["particles 50um"], aqdata["particles 100um"]
            )
            label.config(text=concentration_units, font=("Arial", 14))  # Increase font size
            with open(file_name, 'a') as file1:
                datetime2 = datetime.now()
                data = "{},{},{},{},{},{},{}".format(
                    datetime2, aqdata["particles 03um"], aqdata["particles 05um"],
                    aqdata["particles 10um"], aqdata["particles 25um"],
                    aqdata["particles 50um"], aqdata["particles 100um"])
                file1.write('\n')
                file1.write(data)
            
            # Update the graph
            times.append(datetime2)
            pm25_values.append(aqdata["particles 03um"])

            ax.clear()
            ax.plot(times, pm25_values, label='PM 2.5')
            ax.legend(loc='upper right')
            ax.set_xlabel('Time')
            ax.set_ylabel('PM 2.5 Value')
            ax.set_title('PM 2.5 Value Over Time')
            fig.canvas.draw()

            root.after(1000, collect_data)  # Repeat after 1 second
        except RuntimeError:
            print("Unable to read from sensor, retrying...")
            root.after(1000, collect_data)  # Retry after 1 second

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("PM2.5 Sensor Data")
root.configure(bg="black")
root.geometry("800x600")  # Set initial size of the window

label = tk.Label(root, text="", fg="white", bg="black")
label.pack(side="top", pady=10)  # Center the label

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="black")
frame.pack(side="top", pady=10)  # Center the frame containing buttons

start_button = tk.Button(frame, text="Start", command=start_collection)
start_button.pack(side="left", padx=10)  # Center the start button

stop_button = tk.Button(frame, text="Stop", command=stop_collection, state="disabled")
stop_button.pack(side="left", padx=10)  # Center the stop button

collecting = False

# Setup graph
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlabel('Time')
ax.set_ylabel('PM 2.5 Value')
ax.set_title('PM 2.5 Value Over Time')
times = []
pm25_values = []
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

I uninstalled numpy and installed a clean version, made sure it was the latest 1.26.4. I also added the following library to remedy this error with no success.

```
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev
```

Comment: maybe you have to install `libopenblas`. Using `apt search libopenblas` on LInux Mint I see libraries `libopenblas0` `libopenblas-base` and `libopenblas-dev`